# Generating PDF from template dynamically

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf template with placeholder for a list of people. I can use acro fields to populate their names but the problem is, the list have to be of variable length. 
This means that there may be from 1 to 16 people on the list and there should not be any gaps in resulting pdf (so I can't leave blank space in the middle of the page if I have only 2 people).
What's the easiest way of generating such pdfs? 
PdfBox solution is preferred but not a must.

Comment: Can you post a sample template? And describe the requirements in more detail? E.g. is reflowing of content of paragraphs necessary? Is reflowing across page boundaries necessary?  In general PDF is not the right format for such dynamic templating but maybe your case is simple enough.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post my real sample template. I don't uderstand what reflowing of paragraph means, but reflowing of page boundaries is not necessary, list will always fit in one page. Right now i'm tring to use Apache FOP to generate dynamic XML and render it to PDF, but i hope that there is an easier way.

Comment: *Unfortunately I can't post my real sample template* - in that case please create a dummy template and give examples for replacement scenarios (long entries, short entries, many, few) with the same. Unless the requirements are cleared, I would vote for using some xsl-to-pdf or html-to-pdf approach.